# Estimating the parameter of a Bernoulli distribution using probabilistic modeling and the MAP estimation

Tags: maximum-likelihood, lagrange-multipliers, map-estimation

Suppose you tossed a coin multiple times. Sometimes you got heads and other times you got tails. You recorded your experiment in a dataset $ X$. Now you want to estimate the parameter θ (which represents the probability of a coin landing heads) of the Bernoulli distribution using probabilistic modeling. You want to do MAP (Maximum A Posteriori) estimation of parameter $\theta $ where the likelihood is the Bernoulli distribution and the prior is the Gaussian distribution.

Posterior distribution: $P(\theta\mid X)=P(X\mid \theta)\times P(\theta) / P(X)$   where $X={x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n}$

Likelihood: $P(X\mid \theta)=P(x_1\mid \theta)\times P(x_2\mid\theta)\ldots\times P(x_n\mid\theta)$ because the realizations are i.i.d and $P(x_i\mid\theta)$ is the Bernoulli distribution

Prior: $P(\theta)$ is the Gaussian distribution with the parameters $\mu$ as the mean and $\sigma$ as the standard deviation.

For doing the MAP estimation, I have the following questions:

1. knowing that $\theta$ is conditioned: $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ (because it is a probability), does this mean that we have to use the Lagrange multiplier method (Please answer this question before moving to the next one)?
2. Knowing that σ and μ are connected with a formula. $\sigma=(E(X^2)−\mu^2)^{1/2}$ (for the continuous case), does this mean that we have to use the Lagrange multiplier method? if yes, then how will this will be calculated in the continuous case (i.e. I tried to calculate $\sigma$  but it is a complicated task in the continuous case and I do not know if it is even possible)
3. Could you clarify how to do the MAP estimation in this case (kindly clarify it mathematically if possible)

I am interested in the answers for all these three points, but an answer to any of these questions are also welcome!

P.S. I am a computer science engineer (i.e. statistics is not my domain), so please be patient with me.

Comment: Note that a Gaussian prior is inappropriate, as $\theta \in (0,1)$ but the support of the Gaussian distribution is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please add the appropriate tag and show us what you've tried.

Comment: You take the product of the prior density and the likelihood to give something proportional to the density of the posterior distribution.  If you insist on the MAP (there is no loss function for which it is the best choice as a point estimate from a continuous posterior distribution) then you want the mode of the posterior distribution, which you can find as the value of $\theta$ which maximises the   product of the prior density and the likelihood.  There should be no need for a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you for your response. No, it is not homework. Actually, I know how to estimate it using MLE (Maximum likelihood estimation). However, it occurred to my mind to use MAP estimation with Gaussian and see what will be the result. When doing so (without a Lagrange multiplier), I got =μ,  σ=0 only. That's why I thought I might have done something wrong.

Comment: @jbowman you mentioned that "Note that a Gaussian prior is inappropriate". Do you mean by "inappropriate" it is wrong? 
I am asking because I am already limiting the range of   in the conditions between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your response. You mentioned "(there is no loss function for which it is the best choice as a point estimate from a continuous posterior distribution)" I did not understand this statement, especially the "loss function". Here I am maximizing the value of the posterior which itself will be the loss function (up to what I know) if you multiply it by -1 and take arg min instead of arg max of the parameter. Could you please clarify your point?

Comment: @Herny you mentioned "There should be no need for a Lagrange multiplier." could you please elaborate ( 0≤θ≤1 is a constraint and up to what I know when having constraints then we must use a Lagrangian multiplier)

Comment: @jbowman Could you please answer my first two questions (assuming the Gaussian distribution is appropriate i.e. just consider them general questions). Also, in a Gaussian distribution σ and μ are always connected in a mathematical relation (i.e. constrained). Does this mean that every time we want to find a maxima for a posterior distribution that includes a Gaussian distribution we have to use a Lagrangian multiplier? if not, then kindly elaborate.

Comment: @MosabShaheen There are many misconceptions in what you have written.  A [loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) here is the cost of errors in your point estimate.  There is no relationship between the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in a Gaussian distribution (the only requirement is that $\sigma>0$ which is unrelated to $\mu$).  Your prior should be specified at the start, without unknown parameters. Since $0\le \theta\le 1$, that interval or a subset of it should be the support of your prior distribution, but a Gaussian distribution has support on the whole of $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Henry Thank you for clarifying. It made many points clear to me but some points are still not clear and I appreciate you being patient with me. Regarding the loss function: if there is a closed-form solution for the MAP estimation then there will be no need for the loss function because we find it by differentiating. I think you meant that when there is no closed-form solution so which loss function to use!! but in this case, we use expectation maximization which is an iterative method for finding the solution, isn't it?

Comment: @Henry Regarding the parameter of the Gaussian distribution: isn't the standard deviation always calculated from the mean and the data whether it is used in the Gaussian distribution or not? in this case, there will always be a relationship (constraint) between them. Please correct me if I am wrong (I am just repeating my point because I did not understand yours and it is not for proving my point and not for arguing).

Comment: @Henry for the prior: "without unknown parameters" you are right. However, I intentionally did not mention the extra parameters in the posterior distribution because it will make the steps to find the posterior long and it will distract the reader.

Comment: @Henry for the last point 0≤≤1: I got it and it makes more sense. However, it raised the same doubt for me: how will we ensure that the value we are getting in the estimation is not beyond the support if we are not including the support as a constraint? In other words, suppose for example I defined a distribution that is identical to the Gaussian distribution and has the support 0≤≤1 then how can I enforce this support (0≤≤1) in the estimation?

Comment: 1. The parameters of the prior distribution - $\mu$ and $\sigma$ - are specified, by you, in advance, hence the word "prior".  They are not calculated from the data.  2. I do not know what you mean by "there will always be a constraint between them"; there won't be.  3. I don't understand why you think Lagrange multipliers play any role in this.  There is no closed-form solution to the MAP for the probability parameter of a Binomial distribution with a Gaussian prior on $p$; you will have to find it numerically, and you can just specify a lower and upper bound to the solver at that time.

Comment: @jbowman 1) " and  are specified, by you, in advance" it can be but it is not necessary, because the prior means I have some previous knowledge about the parameter  and the prior in this case is the distribution itself i.e.  follows the Gaussian distribution and this represents the previous knowledge about the parameter . Now,  and  can be estimated from the data; this is called hyper-parameter estimation.

Comment: @jbowman  2) Let me clarify. Suppose we are talking about drawing a card from a box that can be of three colors red, blue, and yellow with the corresponding probabilities P_red, P_blue, P_yellow  there is a constraint between them  P_red+P_blue+P_yellow=1 and we have to use a Lagrangian multiplier in this case to include this constraint for estimation. Similarly, for  and  there is always a constraint/relationship between them because the standard deviation is calculated using the mean e.g.  = sqrt ( sum_i (xi-)^2 / N) for discrete data.

Comment: @jbowman 2 continued) that means if you did not enforce this constraint then you might get in your estimation, for example, 1 and 1 where 1 ≠ sqrt ( sum_i (xi-1)^2 / N) (please notice the not-equal symbol). And in this case, the estimation we got (1 and 1) are not sensible because the standard deviation is calculated from the mean. That's why I am asking how can we enforce this constraint.

Comment: 1. If you are estimating $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the data, you are engaged in Empirical Bayes estimation - unless you have priors on those two parameters too - neither of which you mention in the OP.  2. There is no constraint which forces the estimate of the standard deviation to be as you suggest.  It's just a calculation, and there are other ways of estimating it which lead to different formulae.  3.  You have specified how to calculate the estimates, so you're done.  No need for Lagrange multipliers...

Comment: The answers to your first two questions are 1) No and 2) No.  The answer to your third question is, as I've said in comments, that you will have to use a numerical optimization routine, since there is no closed-form solution to your problem.

Comment: Your concern is exactly the same as wondering if you need to use Lagrange multipliers to ensure that 1 + 1 = 2, because 1 + 1 are constrained to = 2, but what if they don't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147751/discussion-between-mosab-shaheen-and-jbowman).